# Single word request: "attempt to discover"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the best single word to capture the phrase "attempt to discover", as in "attempting to discover the principles of infinite ethics"

Comment: Well, "search for" is only two words.

Answer (score 1):

How about **seek** (one word)

> to *attempt to discover* the principles of infinite ethics
>   to **seek** the principles of infinite ethics

I don't really know what to picture for "principles of infinite ethics". Other options could be

> to **investigate** the principles of infinite ethics
>   to **search for** the principles of infinite ethics

Comment: Or maybe *explore*.

Comment: I don't know what to picture for "principles of infinite ethics". Do they necessarily exist? Are these principles something that is waiting to be discovered, or are they something that can't really be discovered, or only be discovered imperfectly/partially? *attempt to discover* seems to suggest the former, in which case *seek* (or *quest for*) seems like a perfect choice, even if these principles don't (or can't) exist. In the latter case, *investigate* or *research* seem more appropriate, but only if we know they have to exist and can be discovered partially.

Answer (score 0):

One might ***pursue*** the principles of infinite ethics.